# XVBA extension VS CODE : Error in AutoloadModules

Tags: excel, vba, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to use the XVBA extension in VS CODE to develop a VBA application on Excel. But after installing the extension, when I send the code to Excel, I get the following error:

> ERROR IN AUTOLOADMODULES :  Nom du fichier ou de la classe introuvable lors de l'opération de l'Automation

[image]

I've enabled macros in the Excel options, created an index.xlsb file in the same folder. But I can't go any further.

I try with another type : .xlsm

If other people have encountered this type of error, thank you for your feedback ...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I was using a macbook when I encountered this problem.

Secondly, I've changed PCs (windows 11) and encountered the same problem when my work folder is stored on OneDrive.

When the folder is stored on a C:/ pc folder - no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just save your config.json file again or override it, which solved my probelm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).